# Finding conditions that assure that a holomorphic function is constant in a specified region

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $H$ be a real-valued function of two real variables with continuous first partial derivatives. If $h(z)=h(x+i y)= u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is holomorphic in a region $V$, and $H(u,v)=0$. Find a condition on $H$ under which one can conclude that $h$ is a constant. Of course, $H$ as the zero function can do the job, but I do not want a trivial condition, any clue?